# How to access a Checkbox from one User Control to other

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a CheckBox in page 'A' and I want to access that Checkbox in Page 'B'.

What I have tried:
* I'm accessing Page 'A' from Page 'B' by doing the following-

```
Protected WithEvents A1 As A
```

- I've declared a CheckBox in the Page_Load as following:

  Dim chk As CheckBox = CType(A1.FindControl("chk"), CheckBox)
- Page 'B' has number of Case statements and I want to access that CheckBox in one of the Cases, and I'm making that CheckBox Visible by doing the following:

  Case "9"

  chk.Visible = True
- But, It's not working that way. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In ASP.NET, the pages don't all exist (at the same time) like they do in winforms. Think of each page as a separate program.  You can use Session variables to share values between forms, or pass them to another page via QueryString.

Comment: Is `chk` Nothing? What means "it's not working"? Instead of searching a CheckBox with FindControl(which is not searching in child controls), expose a public property in `A` that returns this checkbox.

Comment: I tried that too @TimSchmelter. I've declared a Public ReadOnly Property that returns this CheckBox and Used that property in Page 'B' to access the CheckBox. It's still not working. What I mean by working is that, I just want that CheckBox to be Visible in Page 'B', and I can take care of the rest.

Comment: @tgolisch I'm new to .Net as well as Session Variables. Can you help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: For example, if Page A had a listbox called ShirtSize, you could pass the value to Page B like `Session("ShirtSizeChoice") = ShirtSize.SelectedValue`. On Page B, you could retrieve it like `Select Case Session("ShirtSizeChoice")  [\n] Case "s" CheckBoxSmall.Checked = True`